# If every Sylow subgroup of G is a normal subgroup, show that G is isomorphic to the product of its Sylow subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

If every Sylow subgroup of G is a normal subgroup, show that G is isomorphic to the product of its Sylow subgroups.

I can't figure this out without G being abelian.

Comment: Hint: Let $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_k$ be the distinct normal Sylow subgroups, then check that
$$
H_i\cap \prod_{j\neq i} H_j = \{e\}
$$

Comment: First question you should answer is : $\textbf{when would $G\cong H\times K$ for subgroups $H,K$ of $G$? }$

Comment: Thank you. I have done both of these things. G is isomorphic to the product of H and K when G is abelian, the intersection of the subgroups is only the identity, and HK=G.

Comment: @Mertle : you have to prove $G$ is abelian then do you think it makes any sense to say "G is isomorphic to the product of H and K when G is abelian,"